# Is it possible to search a keyword in CTS Job fields and custom attribute both

Tags: google-cloud-talent-solution

We are implementing CTS job search. We are looking for an implementation where if user searches for a keyword, let's say "Sales", that would then show all matching results that keyword matched in CTS providing fields like: Title, Description, Category, Location, etc OR all matching results that keyword matched any Custom Attribute attached to the job.

Is it possible in Google CTS job search?

When we have passing keyword "Sales", it's only returning results that are matching to CTS core fields like title, description and so on.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging on CTS documentation i found answer for my question.

There is an attribute we have to set in created Company named as "keywordSearchableJobCustomAttributes" that accepts string as field names.

> A list of keys of filterable Job.custom_attributes, whose
>   corresponding stringValues are used in keyword searches. Jobs with
>   stringValues under these specified field keys are returned if any of
>   the values match the search keyword. Custom field values with
>   parenthesis, brackets and special symbols are not searchable as-is,
>   and those keyword queries must be surrounded by quotes.

Below are references.

- https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/companies
- https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/reference/rest/v4beta1/projects.companies#Company.FIELDS.keyword_searchable_job_custom_attributes